# Is it possible to find relative speed?(its speed not velocity)

Tags: speed

I was wondering that relative velocity can be computed easily due its directional nature.
but what about speed?
Speed is not directional so now we cant find relative speed of objects in different directions!
Isn't it

Answer (score 1):

Relative speed is just the magnitude of relative velocity. Apart from this, there isn't another notion of relative speed.